# How to combine a normal function with another function that will combine different text files into one file?

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, with-statement

I want to combine out_fun() to combinefiles(). Currently I have it where out_fun() it writes to file3.txt and then closes it. Next, I have it where out_fun() is called within combinefiles() to write "Hello World" in order to combine out_fun() with combinefiles(). This solution is not working because it ends up printing hello world three separate times in the Python Shell and just says "None" within the file3.txt file. I'm wondering how I can do this so it doesn't make this so it doesn't print "Hello World" three times as I want it only to be printed once like in out_fun() and then I want "Hello World" added to the bottom of combinefiles(). I cannot use return because it gives a syntax error at 'end=""'

```
def out_fun(): 
    print("Your number is ", end="")
    print(random.randint(0,5)
output = out_fun() 
file = open("file3.txt","w") 
file.write(str(output))
file.close() 

def file1():
    fileone = input("Please tell me your name: ")
    fileone_file = open("file1.txt", "w")
    a = fileone_file.write(fileone)
    fileone.file.close()
file1()

def file2():
    filetwo = input("Please tell me your favorite color: ")
    filetwo_file = open("file2.txt", "w")
    a = filetwo_file.write(filetwo)
    filetwo.file.close()
file2()

def combinefiles():
    filenames = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
        with open('file3.txt', 'w') as outfile:
            for names in filenames:
                with open(names) as infile:
                    outfile.write(infile.read())
                    outfile.write("\n")
                    output = out_fun()
                    outfile.write(str(output))
        outfile.close()
combinefiles()
```

Expected text file output on separate lines:

```
John (name)
Blue (color)
12 (random number)
```

Comment: The `out_fun` function does not `return` a value so `output` will always be `None`. Don't use `print`. Instead return the string `return f"Your number is {random.randint(0,5)}"`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks that worked! However, when I look in the text file, I see that the number is printed twice when put into combinefiles() function. Do you know a solution so it can only be printed once?

Comment: Right now you are using a `for` loop that is looping over a 2-element array, so the code in the loop is being called twice. Could you be more explicit about what you want the output/results to look like?

Comment: @nullromo I have edited my code and have added in the functions file1 and file2 and the expected text file output. Thank you.

Comment: I think this turned out to just be an indentation error. I posted a complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version that creates your desired output:

```py
import random

def out_fun():
    return f'Your number is {random.randint(0,5)}'

with open('file3.txt','w') as file:
    file.write(out_fun())

def file1():
    fileone = input('Please tell me your name: ')
    with open('file1.txt', 'w') as fileone_file:
        fileone_file.write(fileone)
file1()

def file2():
    filetwo = input('Please tell me your favorite color: ')
    with open('file2.txt', 'w') as filetwo_file:
        filetwo_file.write(filetwo)
file2()

def combinefiles():
    filenames = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
    with open('file3.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        for name in filenames:
            with open(name) as infile:
                outfile.write(infile.read())
                outfile.write('\n')
        outfile.write(out_fun())
combinefiles()
```

Note that the final `outfile.write` call is **outside** the `for` loop.

A few notes:

- You should prefer using `with` to open files instead of `open`/`close`.
- When using `with`, you do not normally need to explicitly close files.
- Remember the difference between printing a value (sending it to the console as a string) and returning a value (using the actual value in the code)